why does SLIC changes the original image when printing it with boundaries? And is it possible to reduce the thickness of boundaries?
I got a NIFTI image. I transferred it into nparray and tried to apply SLIC to it. But the printed image with boundaries does not look right.
Here is the code I use to apply SLIC and print the images:
import numpy as np
from skimage.segmentation import slic
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.segmentation import find_boundaries, mark_boundaries

segments_1 = slic(region, n_segments=25, compactness=0.05, sigma=1, start_label=1, channel_axis=None)

boundaries_1 = find_boundaries(segments_1, mode='inner')

image_with_boundaries_1 = mark_boundaries(region, boundaries_1, color=(1, 0, 0))

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(region, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Original Image')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(image_with_boundaries_1, cmap='gray')
plt.title('gray')
plt.axis('off')

The left one is the original image, while the right one is the printed image with boundaries
Also, I'm wondering if it is possible to reduce the thickness of the boundaries. It seems that pixels between the boundaries are missed for the segmentation. Will there be loss of info?
At first, I thought it might be because of the value of 'cmap'. But it shows all the same with different values. It feels like there is something left, but too bright. I tried to rescale it. Didn't really work.

please post code as text, not as images. [tour], [ask], [mre], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]
